# Copy div on click on element in this div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to copy `.step` div when the `.delete` div is clicked. The copied div should appear just underneath the step with clicked `.delete` div

```
      <div class="step" >
          <h2> sth </h2>

          <div class="copy"></div>
          <div class="delete"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="step" >
          <h2> sth </h2>

          <div class="copy"></div>
          <div class="delete"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="step" >
          <h2> sth </h2>

          <div class="copy"></div>
          <div class="delete"></div>
      </div>
```

here is my wrong jQuery:

```
  $('.copy').click(function(){
   var newDiv = $(this).parent().innerHTML;
   $(this).parent().after(newDiv);
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be jQuery `.html()` rather than DOM `innerHTML` since `parent()` returns a jQuery wrapper.

But there is no need to mess around with HTML source; use `clone()`.

```
$(this).parent().after($(this).parent().clone());
```

(Also `clone(true)` if you want to copy across existing event handlers, ie `click()` on the new copy also copies that copy.)

Comment: also html will only copy the contents of the div, not the div itself

Comment: This answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.copy').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().after($(this).parent().html());
});
```

See if that works for you.